# Error when returning a string from a function

Tags: c, string, function, return

This is from a Codewars challenge so I'll leave out unnecessary code from this function.  Basically if `n <= 1`, I need to return an empty string.

```
char* sc(int n)
{
    if(n > 1) {
        //irrelevant code
    }

    //return strdup("");
    return "";
}
```

If the value being passed is `-1`, when I use `return "";` I get a "Test crashed" message but when I use `return strdup("");` I pass the test.  Just wondering why this is?

Edit:
This is how the function is called.  It is only the last test that fails.

```
#include <criterion/criterion.h>
#include <string.h>

char* sc(int);

void dotest(int n, const char* expect)
{
  char* actual = sc(n);
  cr_expect(!strcmp(actual, expect), "Expected: '%s', got: '%s'\n", expect, actual);
  free(actual);
}

Test(the_multiply_function, should_pass_all_the_tests_provided) {
    dotest(2,"Aa~ Pa! Aa!");
    dotest(6, "Aa~ Aa~ Aa~ Aa~ Aa~ Pa! Aa!");
    dotest(7, "Aa~ Aa~ Aa~ Aa~ Aa~ Aa~ Pa!");
    dotest(10, "Aa~ Aa~ Aa~ Aa~ Aa~ Aa~ Aa~ Aa~ Aa~ Pa!");
    dotest(1, "");
    dotest(-1, "");
}
```

Comment: @Luv: they are returning a string literal, that has static storage duration.

Comment: @Mat you are right. The problem seems to be the free here

Comment: WHat does the function return if n > 1 ? This is relevant.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It returns the correct answer (the expected strings in the Test function) .  I pass those tests, its just the -1 test I fail but now I know this was due to the free statement.  That's why that code is irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For usage of `free()`, from `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.3 (*emphasis mine*)

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, **if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function,** or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, **the
>   behavior is undefined.**

and, for [`strdup()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) (*again emphasis mine*)

> The `strdup()` function returns a pointer to a new string which is a duplicate of the string `s`. **Memory for the new string is obtained with `malloc()`, and can be freed with `free()`.**

So, when you use `return strdup("");`, the pointer which is returned is eligible to be passed to `free()` - everything is alright.

OTOH, by saying `return "";`, you're returning a pointer to the first element of a string literal which is not a suitable candidate to be passed to `free()`, as mentioned above, it invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The crash or segmentation fault is ***one of the many*** side effects of UB.

Answer (score 2):

The challenge seem to require that the function returns a dynamic allocated string. This can be seen from:

```
char* actual = sc(n);
...
free(actual);  // free is for dynamic allocated memory
```

Therefore the function must use a `malloc` type function to allocate the string. `strdup` does that, i.e. it allocates dynamic memory and makes a copy of the string (i.e. `""` in this code)  into that memory.

Just doing `return "";` will return the address to a string (i.e. `""`) with static storage duration, i.e. some memory that can't be freed. Calling `free` on memory with static storage duration leads to undefined behavior which may be a program crash.

Answer (score 2):

The fucntion sc() is returning a string constant "". String constants automatically allocated in a separate memory.

sc() is returning address of this string constant. In do test(), you are storing the address in actual variable and freeing it.

You are not suppose to free that memory. Just remove `free(actual);`.